# Issue with JSON::encode_json on later version of Perl

Tags: perl

For some reason the JSON perl module isn't playing ball on my new server. I get the error:

```
encountered object '1', but neither allow_blessed, convert_blessed nor allow_tags settings are enabled (or TO_JSON/FREEZE method missing) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/JSON.pm line 173.
```

The code is the same as it was on another server:

```
my $new_files = reload_image_list();

use Data::Dumper;
print $IN->header;
print Dumper({ foo => $new_files} );
print JSON::encode_json( { all_results => $new_files } );
```

I've confirmed the $new_files variable is what I'm expecting (an arrayref), so I'm unsure why I get this error now :/

Answer (score 1):

Typical! As soon as I write the post out and post it, I find the answer!

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869641

They suggest removing `libjson-xs-perl`, so I did:

`apt-get remove libjson-xs-perl`

...restarted Apache, and now it seems to work :) Hopefully that hasn't broken anything else!